# Laravel 5, authenticating and displaying user roles

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, roles, laravel-5

I am very new to using pivot tables full stop never mind within Laravel, my apps have never been too complicated.  Here is my issue.

I have setup a new test site, it has 3 tables.

users
roles
user_role

In the User model I have defined the relationship with the Role model as:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```

Ok, so this should be easy enough I thought.  First of all authenticating a user is simple

```
Auth::user();
```

Keeping this very simple all I really want to do is display the role or roles the user has.  If I put this in a view:

```
Aith::user()->roles;
```

I get the following result

```
[{"id":"7","name":"Administrator","created_at":"2015-03-19      00:14:53","updated_at":"2015-03-19 00:14:53","pivot":{"user_id":"1","role_id":"7"}}]
```

Now that is spot on, however I will need to sound totally daft here.  How do I just get it to return the role name?

Instead of the result above I just simply want it to display:

```
Administrator
```

Nothing more.

Comment: **Which** role name? You've got a `belongsToMany`, which means a user may have more than one role.

Comment: Good question, the solution to that would be to cycle through the role names and list them all.  For authentication purposes I guess the app would need to know what the user is trying to do and whether they have a role which allows it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

either this to get the first record

```
Auth::user()->roles->first()->name
```

or use a loop

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->roles as $role)
    {{ $role->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Yup, that's it Dallin, thanks.  It was the first()->name that I was getting wrong.